# Bootstrap - Second Column Top Padding?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with two columns. All works great and responsive however, i noticed when i resize to mobile view, the second columns stacks underneath (great!) however the content is right below the content of the first column so looks terrible.

Is there a way to create this spacing? Tried targeting with classes and ID's and playing with margins and paddings but nothing seems to make a difference.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Little bit of content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Little bit of content</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try adding the margins to the media query like so? @media screen and (max-width: $mobile) { .container .col-sm-6 { margin-top: 10px }  }.  Or is another style over riding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to create this spacing?

Yes there is. It could be achieved by using `@media` queries to apply some styles to the 2nd, 3rd, ... columns on specific break points. For instance:

```css
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    [class*="col-"] + [class*="col-"] {
        padding-top: 1em; /* for instance */
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Little bit of content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Little bit of content</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```